# Is there a way to force Illustrator to open a downloaded SVG (rather than the browser)?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser, adobe-illustrator, svg

I have Illustrator set as the default for all SVGs but whenever I download an SVG, when I click on the download inside the browser, the browser opens the SVG in a new tab. So the only way to open the SVG is by opening up the download folder and then open the SVG from there.

My question is... when I click on the downloaded SVG, is there a way to make it open up inside Illustrator rather than opening up in the browser?

**Some quick info**

- I'm on a Mac
- I've set Illustrator as the default by right-clicking an SVG and going to *Open With...*
- I've also set Illustrator as the default by right-clicking an SVG and opening *Get Info*, setting the default application to Illustrator, and then clicked *Change All*

Answer (score 1):

Chrome seems to ignore system defaults when opening files like this,  choosing to instead open the file itself.You can override that behavior by selecting the download options menu show as three horizontal dots (…) to the right of the download and choosing "Open With System Viewer" to use the system default instead.